# Pause between frame title and TOC

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm using `beamer` for a presentation. What I would like is a pause after the frame title and before the TOC. `\pause` as in

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{my frame title}
\pause
\tableofcontents[]
\end{frame}
```

has no effect.

Comment: Please see the answer to this[link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510417) question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
\onslide<2->{\tableofcontents[]}
```

instead of `\pause`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{my frame title}
\onslide<2->{\tableofcontents[]}
\end{frame}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\section{Second Section}
\begin{frame}
Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, consider marking it as [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) by clicking on the checkmark ✓ next to the score.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to test it, but why not just do this:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My contents}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle

\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```